# What does .shape[] do in "for i in range(Y.shape[0])"?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to break down a program line by line. `Y` is a matrix of data but I can't find any concrete data on what `.shape[0]` does exactly.

```
for i in range(Y.shape[0]):
    if Y[i] == -1:
```

This program uses numpy, scipy, matplotlib.pyplot, and cvxopt.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.shape.html or http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape

Answer (score 146):

The `shape` attribute for numpy arrays returns the dimensions of the array. If `Y` has `n` rows and `m` columns, then `Y.shape` is `(n,m)`. So `Y.shape[0]` is `n`.

```
In [46]: Y = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

In [47]: Y
Out[47]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

In [48]: Y.shape
Out[48]: (3, 4)

In [49]: Y.shape[0]
Out[49]: 3
```

Answer (score 48):

shape is a tuple that gives dimensions of the array..

```
>>> c = arange(20).reshape(5,4)
>>> c
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])

c.shape[0] 
5
```

Gives the number of rows

```
c.shape[1] 
4
```

Gives number of columns

Answer (score 11):

`shape` is a tuple that gives you an indication of the number of dimensions in the array. So in your case, since the index value of `Y.shape[0]` is 0, your are working along the first dimension of your array.

From
[Link](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html#head-62ef2d3c0a5b4b7d6fdc48e4a60fe48b1ffe5006)

```
 An array has a shape given by the number of elements along each axis:
 >>> a = floor(10*random.random((3,4)))

 >>> a
 array([[ 7.,  5.,  9.,  3.],
        [ 7.,  2.,  7.,  8.],
        [ 6.,  8.,  3.,  2.]])

 >>> a.shape
 (3, 4)
```

and http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List#shape has some more
examples.

Comment: @HipsterCarlGoldstein Just a friendly note, if any one of these answers provided solved your problem
please consider [accepting it by clicking the checkmark next to the
answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). This
will give you and the answerer both some rep points and also mark this
problem as solved - thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In python, Suppose you have loaded up the data in some variable train:

```
train = pandas.read_csv('file_name')
>>> train
train([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 5.,  1.,  2.]],)
```

I want to check what are the dimensions of the 'file_name'. I have stored the file in train

```
>>>train.shape
(2,3)
>>>train.shape[0]              # will display number of rows
2
>>>train.shape[1]              # will display number of columns
3
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python `shape()` is use in pandas to give number of row/column:

Number of rows is given by:

```py
train = pd.read_csv('fine_name') //load the data
train.shape[0]
```

Number of columns is given by

```py
train.shape[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

`shape()` consists of array having two arguments rows and columns.

if you search `shape[0]` then it will gave you the number of rows.
`shape[1]` will gave you number of columns.