# How do you implement ECDF in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, statsmodels, ecdf, index-error

I'm trying to implement the empirical distribution function from a [paper](https://openlab.ncl.ac.uk/publicweb/publications/iswc197s-hammerla.pdf) that has the MATLAB implementation on page 3. Here's my Python version of it.

I converted it according to the [NumPy for MATLAB users documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) while taking into account how `statsmodels` [implements](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution.ECDF.html) `ECDF`

```
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF     

def ecdf_representation(D, n):
     """calculate ECDF from D at n points"""
     m = np.mean(D)
     X = []
     for d in xrange(D.shape[0] + 1):
         func = ECDF([D[:, d] + np.random.randn(np.shape(D[:, d])) * 0.01])
         ll = func(np.linspace(0, 1, n))
         X = [X, ll]
     X = [X, m]
     plt.plot(X)
     plt.show()
     return X
```

I get the error:

```
line 25, in ecdf_representation
func = ECDF([D[:, d] + np.random.randn(np.shape(D[:, d]))])
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Doesn't `D.shape[0]` return the number of columns? So, `D[:, d]` should work right? What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

D.shape[0] will return rows, not columns:

[What does .shape[] do in "for i in range(Y.shape[0])"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200268/what-does-shape-do-in-for-i-in-rangey-shape0)

D.shape[1] will return columns

Comment: That solved the error in the OP, but now I get `IndexError: tuple index out of range`. Any thoughts on why that's happening? Also, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: The line it happens on is `for d in xrange(D.shape[1] + 1):`

Comment: Try range instead of xrange. Or are you using a huge amount of data?

Comment: I still get `for d in range(0, D.shape[1] + 1): IndexError: tuple index out of range`. The data frame I'm passing in has about 554 rows. 5 columns though.

Comment: Printing `D.shape[1]` returns `IndexError: tuple index out of range` as well.

Comment: You'll want to verify that D is a matrix first. And then don't run it through a function to test, but just print D and then print D.shape[1] to test.

Comment: It's actually an array. I changed it to `D.shape[0]` and I get `func = ECDF(([D[:, d] + np.random.randn(np.shape(D[:, d])) * 0.01]))
IndexError: too many indices for array`

Comment: The matlab code was written for a matrix. So you might need to look things over. Even if you don't want it to be a matrix in the end, it might be best to get it working the same way the matlab code works, and then go back and make edits

Comment: I changed some of my other functions to pass in a matrix. However, the line `func = ECDF(([D[:, d] + np.random.randn(np.shape(D[:, d])) * 0.01]))` now gets `TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an index`. I'm guessing `np.shape(D[:, d]))` returns a tuple. How would I change that to conform to Python?

Comment: Yeap, so now you want to change stuff to work for a matrix and not an index. So change to"

Comment: for d in ... remove range